# in flask, give user a list of options to select from with arbitrary length

Tags: python, forms, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

i'm new to flask, and python in general so let me know if i'm doing anything wrong...

i'm learning by building a web-app. my current goal is to make playlists on spotify from user input. everything i'm trying to do here i have already made work for myself in pycharm scripts, it's the web-dev and interacting with the user part i'm struggling with atm.

i want to:

1. take input (artist name) from user (done)
2. send artist name as search term to spotify and return a list of dictionaries of matching artists. these dictionaries have a bunch of info including 'name' and 'id'. (done)
3. display the names in the result dicts to the user who will select which to include in their playlist. (please help!)
4. use the list of ids which match the selected artists to interogate spotify for all the tracks by those artists and create a playlist.

i just need help with #3

i have a functioning flask / bootstrap web-app that allows user to authenticate via spotify and input the artist name and which conducts the search and returns the list of dicts. i'm using flask forms to take the input, and assume i'll use another to display the results as radio-button fields for user to select one/many from but the list is of arbitrary length and i don't know how to pass this dynamically to the html. the dictionary i make from the spotify response has names as keys and ids as values - i only want to pass the names to the user to select from, but i'll need to maintain acces to the dictionaries so i can retrieve the ids for the spotify search later...

i've added the code i use to make and populate the playlists in case anyone likes/wants it/has any comments.

my code:

python

```
class ArtistTracksForm(FlaskForm):
    artist = StringField('Who are you searching for?')
    submit = SubmitField('search')

...
@app.route('/artist_playlist', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def artist_playlist():

# prepare spotify

    cache_handler = sp.cache_handler.CacheFileHandler(cache_path=session_cache_path())
    auth_manager = sp.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(cache_handler=cache_handler)
    if not auth_manager.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        return redirect('/')
    spotify = sp.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)

#get form

    form = ArtistTracksForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        artist = form.artist.data
        results = spotify.search(q=artist, type='artist')
        items = results['artists']['items']

#make a dictionary of results

        names_list = {}
        for item in items:
            artist_name=item['name']
            artist_id = item['id']
            names_list.update({artist_name:artist_id})

# temp. make a string of keys (artist names) by unpacking the dict

        name_string = ''
        for name in [*names_list]:
            name_string = name_string + name + ", "
        return name_string

@app.route('/handle_data')
def handle_data():
    data_handler = request.form['APform']
```

i don't really know what i'm doing with the 'action=' and handle_data(): parts but can work that out, it's the dynamically sized list of fields and interacting between python and html i'm really perplexed by

html.j2:

```
{% extends "layout.html.j2" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('handle_data')}}" name=APform>
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Artist Playlists</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.artist.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.artist(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

any input greatly appreciated, i've been searching google and SO for hours now...
thanks

here's the python code i use to get all the tracks from all the albums that an artist has at least one track on, and make a playlist on my spotify account for each artist.... max tracks is 10k so it makes multiple if that is exceeded... in case that's of interest to anyone who read this far... i've been making sql databases and inserting huge spotify playlists into my account.  XD

```
def get_releases(list_of_artist_dicts, form='dict'):
    """takes list of artist dicts
    return list of dicts (form = 'dict)
    or list of id strings 'form='list'"""
    album_list = []
    for artist_dict in list_of_artist_dicts:  # iterate artist dicts
        artist = artist_dict['artist']
        artist_id = artist_dict['artist_id']
        results = sp.artist_albums(artist_id)  # call spotify for artist_album details
        releases = results['items']
        while results['next']:  # check for more pages
            results = sp.next(results)
            releases.extend(results['items'])
        for release in releases:
            album_group = release['album_group']
            album_type = release['album_type']
            album = release['name']
            album_id = release['id']
            spotify_album_url = release['external_urls']['spotify']
            release_date = release['release_date']
            release_date_precision = release['release_date_precision']
            release_date = date_stripper(release_date,
                                         release_date_precision)  # convert date string to datetime obj, insert spurious 1s if precision < day
            album_artist = release['artists'][0]['name']  # get (first) album artist details
            album_artist_id = release['artists'][0]['name']
            release_dict = {
                'artist': artist,
                'artist_id': artist_id,
                'album_artist': album_artist,
                'album_artist_id': album_artist_id,
                'album': album,
                'album_id': album_id,
                'album_group': album_group,
                'album_type': album_type,
                'release_date': release_date,
                'release_date_precision': release_date_precision,
                'spotify_album_url': spotify_album_url
            }
            if form == 'dict':
                album_list.append(release_dict)
            if form == 'list':
                album_list.append(release_dict['album_id'])
    return album_list


def get_tracks(list_of_artist_dicts, form=dict):
    """ takes list of artist dicts, returns a list of track dicts, or track ids if form=list """
    track_dicts_list = []
    for artist_dict in list_of_artist_dicts:
        album_list = []
        artist = artist_dict['artist']
        artist_id = artist_dict['artist_id']
        artist_dict = [artist_dict]
        release_list = get_releases(artist_dict, 'dict')
        for release in release_list:
            album_id = release['album_id']
            album_list.append(album_id)
        for offset in range(0, len(album_list), 20):
            batch = album_list[offset:offset + 20]
            result = sp.albums(batch)
            albums_batch = result['albums']
            for batched_album in albums_batch:
                album = batched_album['name']
                album_id = batched_album['id']
                #   release_date = batched_album['release_date'] tracks dont have release dates?
                album_type = batched_album['album_type']
                track_count = len(batched_album['tracks']['items'])
                for act in batched_album['artists']:
                    album_artist = act['name']
                    album_artist_id = act['id']
                track_id_list = []
                for track in batched_album['tracks']['items']:
                    track_artist = track['artists'][0]['name']
                    track_artist_id = track['artists'][0]['id']
                    title = track['name']
                    spotify_track_url = track['external_urls']['spotify']
                    track_id = track['id']
                    track_id_list.append(track_id)
                    track_dict = {
                        'artist': artist,
                        'artist_id': artist_id,
                        'album_artist': album_artist,
                        'album_artist_id': album_artist_id,
                        'album': album,
                        'album_id': album_id,
                        'track_artist': track_artist,
                        'track_artist_id': track_artist_id,
                        'title': title,
                        'track_id': track_id,
                        'album_type': album_type,
                        'spotify_track_url': spotify_track_url
                    }
                    track_dicts_list.append(track_dict)
    if form == 'list':
        return track_id_list
    return track_dicts_list

def make_playlist(playlist_name='python_play'):
    """creates a playlist on user account, returns playlist_id"""
    user = sp.me()['id']
    return sp.user_playlist_create(user=user,name=playlist_name)['id']


def add_to_playlist(playlist_id, track_list):
    sp.playlist_add_items(items=track_list, playlist_id=playlist_id)


def check_playlist_exists(term):
    """ searches current user's playlists for playlist_name = term returns true if exists"""
    limit = 50
    offset = 0
    current_names = []
    for step in range (0,1000,50):
        current_playlists = sp.current_user_playlists(limit=limit, offset=offset)['items']
        for playlist in current_playlists:
            current_names.append(playlist['name'])
        offset += 50
    if term in current_names:
        return True


def get_alpha(my_dict):
    sorter = my_dict['name']
    sortering = sorter.lower()
    return sortering


def create_playlist_all_artist_tracks(artist_list):
    artist_list.sort(reverse=True, key=get_alpha)           # reverse sort list so playlists will be front-sorted in spotify
    already = []
    making = []
    for artist in artist_list:
        artist_name = artist['name']
        artist_id = artist['id']
        playlist_name = f"{artist_name} and friends - all tracks from all releases including features_on- made in python"
        if check_playlist_exists(playlist_name):
            print (f"ALREADY EXISTS - {playlist_name}")
            already.append(playlist_name)
        else:
            print (f'PLAYLIST NOT FOUND making playlist "{playlist_name}"')
            making.append(playlist_name)
            artist_tracks = get_track_id_list_artist(artist_id)
            if len(artist_tracks) < 10000:
                playlist_id = make_playlist(playlist_name)
                start = 0
                for step in range(start, len(artist_tracks), 100):
                    batch = artist_tracks[start:start + 100]
                    add_to_playlist(playlist_id, batch)
                    start += 100
            else:
                count = 1
                begin = 0
                start=0
                for section in range(begin, len(artist_tracks), 10000):
                    playlist_id = make_playlist(f"{playlist_name} number {count}")
                    chunk = artist_tracks[begin:begin + 10000]
                    for step in range(start, len(chunk), 100):
                        batch = artist_tracks[start:start + 100]
                        add_to_playlist(playlist_id, batch)
                        start += 100
                    count+=1
                    begin += 10000
    print ("PLAYLISTS ALREADY MADE:")
    pprint (already)
    print ("NEW PLAYLISTS CREATED :")
    pprint (making)
```

Comment: if you want to send `<form method="POST"`  to `/handle_data` then it needs `@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['POST'])` to get this `POST`

Comment: normally inside template you could use `{% for in ...%}... {% endfor %}` to generate checkboxes for all item in dictionary. But you use `wtform` and it may need first to create special class Form, fill it and later send to template - and it should display it correctly.

Comment: wherre is function which uses `html.j2` to render page?

Comment: thanks @furas in the end i learned about sessions and used those instead.